# How to update mysql data in springmvc?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc

In my Spring project I want to update mysql table field according to the url :

I have url below:

```
localhost:9191/access/name/122(It can be any number,this is the stu_id)
```

I want to fetch the id from url and then update the name field of the corrsponding mysql table

In my database I have the table name "user".

mysql query is:

```
UPDATE student
SET name='rahul'
WHERE stu_id='122(or whatever the number)';
```

How can I do that In spring mvc????
I have done the below

User.java is:

```
public User(String stu_id, String name) {
        super();
        this.stu_id = stu_id;
        this.name = name;
    }
```

UserDao.java

```
public interface UserDao {


     public void updateUser(User user);

}
```

UserDaoImpl.java is:

```
@Transactional
@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
@Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void updateUser(User user) {

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(user);
        }
    }
```

UserService.java is:

```
public interface UserService {

    User updateUser(String stu_id, String name);

}
```

UserServiceImpl.java is:

```
@Service("userService")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

public User updateUser(String stu_id, String name) {

        //here how can i update the query??????


return user;
}
```

UserController.java is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/access/name/{foo}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public class UserController {



}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use the annotaion in the method:**
@RequestMapping(value="/access/name/{foo}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void foo(@PathVariable("id") int id, HttpServletRequest request) {

}

Then normally how you update the database just perform the regular operation.

Comment: from google I got that I have to edit in UserServiceImpl.java ..But I dont know How to update with that..What I have to write in "UserServiceImpl.java "??

Comment: In "UserServiceImpl.java" call the "UserDaoImpl.java" there based upon your requirement you can use the HQL or SQL or spring JDBC to update the table.You can updatethe table.

Answer (score 0):

call dao method of updateRecord()
i.e. if you using HibernateTemplate then the reference of Hibernate template with call `update()` method directly and pass your pojo obj.
its simply works.
ex.

```
hibernateTemplate.update(pojo);
```

and return it as

```
return hibernateTemplate.update(pojo);
```